# how to do complete validation in one function in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

working on php project want to do validation at once only at all fields of registration form.

- fields
- name
- address
- mobile

all above fields are mandatory so can i write only one function of validation

```
function validateForm()
{
   if (document.myForm.name.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the name");
      document.myForm.name.focus();
      return false;
   }
   if (document.myForm.address.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the address");
      document.myForm.address.focus();
      return false;
   }
...
}
```

instead of this how can i write only one function code so that i do not need to check all textbox values separately .

Comment: This is javascript. Not PHP and certainly nothing to do with phpmyadmin

Comment: And to answer your question: use an array.

Comment: thanks...please help me can you show me example with my fields ? m new bie

Comment: Use JQuery validation plugin and once the data has been posted verify it again from your PHP code. Never trust the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add Ids to your input fields...

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address"/>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"/>
```

You can then do something like...

```
var Fields = [['name', 'your name'],
              ['mobile', 'your mobile number'],
              ['address', 'your address']]

for(x=0; x<Fields.length; x++) {
    if(document.getElementById(Field[x][0]).value == '') {
        alert('Please enter ' + Field[x][1]);
        return false;
    }
}
```